# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException when trying to use setSelectionPath in JTree

Tags: java, swing, exception, jtree

I have been trying after clicking a button to set the selection path in a JTree. The code sets the path correctly, but each time I click it I get a

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
at com.treeview.main.iui.SelectableTree.actionPerformed(SelectableTree.java:225)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And I have no idea what causes it. I read that it happens when you multiple threads try to access the same resource but I can't see the problem.

Here is the code I'm trying to run:

```
/**
     * Handles the event when a button is clicked.
     */
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // If button "Force adaptation is clicked"
            if (arg0.getSource() == forceAdapt) {
                    // ModelContainer.getInstance().getAdaptedTree().removeAllChildren();
                    // tree.setModel(new DefaultTreeModel(ModelContainer.getInstance()
                    // .getAdaptedTree()));
                    // treeModel.reload();
            } else if (arg0.getSource() == showAll) {
                    expandFullTree(tree, ModelContainer.getInstance().getAdaptedTree());
                    // If button "Show All" is clicked
                    // tree.setModel(new DefaultTreeModel(ModelContainer.getInstance()
                    // .getFullTree()));
                    // treeModel.reload();
            }
            // In case recommendation button was clicked.

            for (JButton button : recommendButtons) {
                    if (arg0.getSource() == button) {
                            TreeHandler th = new TreeHandler();
                            TreeItem node = th.getNodeByName(ModelContainer.getInstance()
                                            .getAdaptedTree(), button.getText());

                            tree.setSelectionPath(new TreePath(node.getPath()));
                    }
            }

    }
```

Those two methods populate the ArrayList with buttons:

```
 /**
 * Handles tree selection event.
 */
public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent event) {
    selectedNode = (TreeItem) tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();

    // If there's predecessors.
    if (!lastSelectedNode.getId().equals("-1")) {
        // Display selection in bottom bar.
        currentSelectionField.setText("Current Selection: "
                + selectedNode.toString() + " Prev Node : "
                + lastSelectedNode.toString());
        /*
         * Increase the clicks in the transition matrix and updates the
         * probability transition matrix.
         */
        ModelContainer.getInstance().increaseClicksOnElement(
                Integer.parseInt(selectedNode.getId()) - 1,
                Integer.parseInt(lastSelectedNode.getId()) - 1);
        // Recalculate the Markovian matrix.
        ModelContainer.getInstance().recalculateMarkovian();

        // Display recommendations
        displayRecommendations(ModelContainer.getInstance()
                .getNextMarkovians(
                        (Integer.parseInt(selectedNode.getId()) - 1) + "",
                        5));

    }

    lastSelectedNode = selectedNode;

}

public void displayRecommendations(ArrayList<TreeItem> recommend) {

    recommendation.removeAll();

    int place = 2;
    for (TreeItem treeItem : recommend) {
        JButton aButton = new JButton(treeItem.toString());
        aButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(recommendation.getWidth(),
                recommendation.getHeight() / place));
        aButton.addActionListener(this);
        recommendButtons.add(aButton);
        recommendation.add(aButton);
        System.out.println(aButton.getText());
        place = place * 2;
    }
    recommendation.revalidate();
    recommendation.repaint();

}
```

Comment: please add the code to your question so it is accessible in the long term on SO (in case it is no longer accessible on pastebin)

Comment: The only iteration I can see is over `recommendButtons` and you are not modifying that collection within that loop (at least not trivially).  Is any other part of the code adding to/removing from `recommendButtons` at the same time as when you are clicking the button?

Comment: for better help sooner edit your question with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to generate ConcurrentModificationException, be sure that your code distribuded on pastebin isn't an SSCCE, because this/these exceptions can came from rest of your code

Comment: Well I have those two methods where I populate the ArrayList with the buttons:

Comment: Why are you creating new TreeHandler objects inside of the ActionListener? How are these TreeHandler objects related to the JTree? Doesn't the JTree already have a handler attached as a listener?

Comment: TreeHandler is a class that has methods for doing some tree operations, not modifying it though. And yes it has but I want to be able to select a node both from the tree and the buttons

Comment: Don't you need to use the TreeHandler object that has been added already to the JTree and not use one that has been created ad hoc for no apparent reason?

Comment: I agreed with HFOE, [JTree](http://example.com) has own [Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#data), notice all updated to the Swing GUI must be [done on EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: hmm I think I know what's causing it, when I change the selection of the tree it calls the method public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent event) where I populate the ArrayList with the buttons. So I guess this is what causes it?

Comment: Solved it by using a copy of the buttons ArrayList, perhaps not the best solution but works now :(